# How to resize the bootstrap navbar to 900px and center it on the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Just recently pulled out all my hair cause of frustration with this. I have looked on all the stackoverflow pages concerning this but all they talk about is centering the

tags. I am trying to resize my navbar to 900px and center it on the page along with the other elements on my page.

Here is the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/vedine/1/) of what I am talking about. I also want the navbar to scale based on the user's device (keep all the bootstrap functionality).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your #wrapper css as below

```
#wrapper{
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width:900px;
    height:100%;
}
```

`max-width:900px;` will make the width flexible when it goes below 900px. And `margin: 0 auto;` will put your content in the center.

Answer (score 0):

Give the wrapper an `max-width`, and make the `ul` tag `text-align:center`.
Check this out: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/04c2c727/)

```
<div class="navbar">

    <ul>
        <li><a href="">home</a> </li>
        <li><a href="">about</a> </li>
        <li><a href="">jobs</a> </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.navbar {
    max-width: 900px;
    height: 80px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.navbar ul{
    text-align: center;
}
.navbar ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: #ccc;
}
```